# What is the difference between now and yet

Tags: grammar

> I said to friend: "I got screwed". "Want me to explain how?"
>   He replied: "not yet".

I expected "Not now"

Are now and yet same things? I dont think so.

What is difference between now and yet?

As far as I think Yet means until now

And now is the present time

So he used the wrong word in my opinion - am I correct?

Comment: Is this a question? And why is he wrong? If he did not want to hear it at this moment, he would use "Not yet" meaning "later"

Comment: It should be not now.  Yet means until now not now

Comment: Not yet means later

Comment: Any source.....?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=not+yet+meaning

Comment: Tons. Look harder: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yet

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-just-yet

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yet

Comment: "Now now" is a better expression, however if he is busy with something, "Not Yet" means "Wait until I am ready"

Comment: Yeah. I think not now would sound like annoyance from his part. Like he doesn't wanna hear it. But not yet would mean that he can't hear it right now but later he surely will. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I have updated your question to make it clearer what you meant. The update will be visible in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is not necessarily using the wrong word.

"Now now" is a better expression but can come over as rude.

If however he is busy with something, "Not Yet" means "Wait until I am ready"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yet
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-just-yet
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yet